# Inline IF Statement in C#

Tags: c#

How will I write an Inline IF Statement in my C# Service class when setting my enum value according to what the database returned?

For example: When the database value returned is 1 then set the enum value to VariablePeriods, when 2 then FixedPeriods.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The literal answer is:

```
return (value == 1 ? Periods.VariablePeriods : Periods.FixedPeriods);
```

Note that the inline if statement, just like an if statement, only checks for true or false. If (value == 1) evaluates to false, it might not necessarily mean that value == 2. Therefore it would be safer like this:

```
return (value == 1
    ? Periods.VariablePeriods
    : (value == 2
        ? Periods.FixedPeriods
        : Periods.Unknown));
```

If you add more values an inline if will become unreadable and a switch would be preferred:

```
switch (value)
{
case 1:
    return Periods.VariablePeriods;
case 2:
    return Periods.FixedPeriods;
}
```

The good thing about enums is that they have a value, so you can use the values for the mapping, as user854301 suggested. This way you can prevent unnecessary branches thus making the code more readable and extensible.

Comment: @Ysterhak: Glad it helped. I'm still wondering though why you prefer branching over using a cast as suggested by user854301

Answer (score 15):

You can do inline ifs with

```
return y == 20 ? 1 : 2;
```

which will give you 1 if true and 2 if false.

Answer (score 13):

You may define your `enum` like so and use *cast* where needed

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    VariablePeriods = 1,
    FixedPeriods = 2
}
```

Usage

```
public class Entity
{
    public MyEnum Property { get; set; }
}

var returnedFromDB = 1;
var entity = new Entity();
entity.Property = (MyEnum)returnedFromDB;
```

Comment: like this because it prevents branching.

Comment: Already have this in my Entity Class. Need to set the Enum according to what is returned from the DB in my service class. That is why I need to do a Inline IF Statement?

Comment: Nope you can simply set it the property you need

Comment: @Ysterhak: What else does this code than returning a specific Enum value based on the integer value from the database? Isn't that what you wanted? If not you may want to supply your code with a placeholder for the line that you don't know how to write, it may help understanding.

Comment: Setting the enum values to whatever is returned from the database, will make the database and business tier of the application tightly coupled. Best practices dictate that we keep our different application tiers losely coupled for reusability.

Comment: @Rudolf: What alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need : ternary operator, please take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary

Comment: This is the conditional operator. Which just happens to be **a** ternary operator. Any three-parameter operator is 'ternary'.

Answer (score 1):

Enum to int: `(int)Enum.FixedPeriods`

Int to Enum: `(Enum)myInt`