# MySql Update if input parameter is not null

Tags: c#, mysql, null

I'm currently about to implement an API controller that will update fields in a table, but only if the input parameters is not null. I know there's alot about this topic, and I have basically tried every solution.

Basically what I'm looking to achive is that the query will update the fields only if they the parameter is not null.

My query looks like this:

```
 string query = "UPDATE leads SET " +
                               "orgNo = IF(?orgNo IS NULL, orgNo, ?orgNo), " +
                               "companyName = IF(?companyName IS NULL, companyName, ?companyName), " +
                               "name = IF(?name IS NULL, name, ?name), " +
                               "telephone = IF(?telephone IS NULL, telephone, ?telephone), " +
                               "telephone1 = IF(?telephone1 IS NULL, telephone1, ?telephone1), " +
                               "address = IF(?address IS NULL, address, ?address), " +
                               "postalCode = IF(?postalCode IS NULL, postalCode, ?postalCode), " +
                               "city = IF(?city IS NULL, city, ?city), " +
                               "email = IF(?email IS NULL, email, ?email), " +
                               "website = IF(?website IS NULL, website, ?website), " +
                               "callbackDate = IF(?callbackDate IS NULL, callbackDate, ?callbackDate), " +
                               "status = IF(?status IS NULL, status, ?status), " +
                               "stage = IF(?stage IS NULL, stage, ?stage), " +
                               "callDate = IF(?callDate IS NULL, callDate, ?callDate), " +
                               "salesNote = IF(?salesNote IS NULL, salesNote, ?salesNote), " +
                               "totalTries = totalTries + 1, " +
                               "currentTries = currentTries + 1 WHERE leadId = ?leadId;";
```

The parameters looks like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?leadId", lead.lead_id));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?orgNo", null));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?companyName", null));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?name", lead.name));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?telephone", lead.telephone));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?telephone1", lead.telephone1));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?address", lead.address));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?salesNote", DateTime.Now + "|" + agent + "|" + lead.stage + "|" + lead.status + "|" + lead.sales_note.Replace("|", "") + "\r\n"));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?postalCode", lead.postal_code));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?city", lead.city));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?email", lead.email));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?website", lead.website));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?callbackDate", lead.callback_date));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?status", lead.status));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?stage", lead.stage));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?callDate", DateTime.Now));
```

The error I'm getting is this `Column 'companyName' cannot be null`

Note that orgNo, and companyName are the exact same column types, and are both null. Hope someone can give me some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: Consider normalizing the column `salesnote` and split it in individual columns instead of the concatenation. The concatenation will likely bite your behind some day, when you want to filter on some specific part of the information.

Comment: If you use `?` then parameters are positional. So you need to make sure that you are adding them _in the same order_. In other words, add `leadId` **last** not **first**. Plus you should use `DBNull.Value` as mentioned below. This also means that things like `lead.name` will need to become `((object)lead?.name) ?? DBNull.Value`. Alternatively, consider using a lightweight ORM like Dapper since it will do the null handling for you automatically.

Comment: @NiklasChristensen Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=net-5.0) instead of null when passing parameters for a stored procedure.

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#deriving-parameter-information): When you send a `null` parameter value to the server, you must specify DBNull, instead of null.

The reason why is because some SQL servers, and the way C# communicates to them, may not understand that that `null` represents an absence of data and instead the runtime assuming you attempted to use an object that doesn't exist or isn't initialized.

To use `DBNull` is fairly simple, `DBNull` is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object, which means there exists **only one of them** when you start the program.

You do not have to initialize `DBNull` as it's created at runtime. To access it use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.

Here's a short example:

```cs
var sqlParam = new MySqlParameter("?paramName", System.DBNull.Value);

cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
```

Comment: I see, and yet, it works with the orgNo column, which is the exact same column type, and is also null

Comment: do you have an example of how to approach it?

Comment: I see your point, the only issue is that the nulls that I assigned was for testing, and would normally be a property from a class model, which is a null value if not assigned. And even with your example it still gives me the same error

Comment: You could check to see if the property is assigned before passing it as a parameter. If the property is null, pass DBNull instead, if it's not, pass the properties value. You could use an [`inline if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to do that without taking a lot of space [using the `?` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982164/inline-if-statement-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too, but then I realized that replacing the DBNull instead as you're suggesting doesn't makes a diffirence, and still gives me the same error. And a wierd this is that the error is complaning about the companyName column, and not the orgNo column

Comment: Have you verified that `IF(?companyName IS NULL, companyName, ?companyName)` is a valid query when you send an actual value? Or do you receive the same error with **any** input you give it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just remembered that in Sql Server exist the function COALESCE that seems to be the perfect fit here and fortunately you have it also in MySql.

```
string query = "UPDATE leads SET " +
               "orgNo = COALESCE(?orgNo, orgNo), "  + 
               ....
               "WHERE leadId = ?leadId;";
```

> The MySQL COALESCE() function is used for returning the first non-null
> value in a list of expressions. If all the values in the list evaluate
> to NULL, then the COALESCE() function returns NULL.

[More info on COALESCE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-coalesce-function/)